# Why is the size of same struct different?

Tags: c, memory-management

Why is the size of these two `struct` different depending on `#include <stdbool.h>` vs. `typedef enum { false, true } bool;` ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
//typedef enum { false, true } bool;

struct x {
    bool a;
    int b;
    char c;
};

struct y {
    bool b;
    char a;
    int c;
};

int main(void) {

    struct x x;
    struct y y;

    printf("Size of struct x:\t %zu\n", sizeof(x));
    printf("Size of struct y:\t %zu", sizeof(y));

    return 0;
}
```

With `#include <stdio.h>` the results on my machine (Mac, Intel):

```
Size of struct x:    12
Size of struct y:    8
```

I assume the size difference (i.e. `8` and `12`) here is due to C utilizing some kind of memory structure padding.

With `typedef enum { false, true } bool;` the result:

```
Size of struct x:    12
Size of struct y:    12
```

Note: The question is not about structured padding (read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-packing) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)), but why `#include <stdbool.h>` vs.
`typedef enum { false, true } bool;` gives different results to the same lines of code.

Comment: Structure padding. In your `x` there is padding before the `b` to align it to 4 bytes; in `y`, the `bool` and `char` likely need no padding and both fit into a 4-byte block. Looking for a suitable duplicate ...

Comment: Note that `bool` might be 1 byte, 4 bytes, etc.